# Why I need those capacitors in USB 3.0 transmission lines?

Tags: capacitor, usb, circuit-design

[image: USB 3.0 Tx Rx Schematic]

In this picture (originally posted in [this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/139129/how-does-usb-superspeed-electrical-signaling-work)), there are capacitors called "AC Capacitor". Why do I need those capacitors? It is a USB 3.0 SuperSpeed connection, so it would not be an AC-Powered device.

Comment: That is not a USB topology that i have ever seen. USB uses a half duplex (single pair of lines) not full duplex (what you have pictured).

Comment: [Here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/139129/how-does-usb-superspeed-electrical-signaling-work) was the diagram reference, and almost every usb 3.0 connector and device has it's own Tx and Rx, which I know.

Comment: @vini_i you must not be looking at usb 3.0 much then.

Comment: @Passerby You are correct, 3.0 is out of my wheel house.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's powered by DC, the signals are high frequency differential pairs on transformers to prevent the need for dc coupled devices. The AC capacitors couple the differential pairs between the transceiver and receiver, and managed the dc bias blocking.

See the answer by Some-Hardware-Guy on [AC-coupling capacitors for high-speed differential interfaces](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/173691/ac-coupling-capacitors-for-high-speed-differential-interfaces) for a full explanation.

Comment: @BenMiller but that prevents the auto complete recognition of the stack exchange url from working.

Comment: @BenMiller there's another way, I'll do it on my computer later.

Comment: So because the USB communicates by binary signal (which are made of zeros and ones) and it is removable, it is needed for circuit safety, right?

Comment: The caps are part of the impedance / dc blocking required for the performance at these very fast speeds ... see the link in the answer for more details. Not for safety. without them the link fails.

Comment: @Spoon Oh... I must misunderstood that. Thank you for replying me.